# Phalcon.ini is loaded in phpifo but phalcon is not installed

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, phalcon

I am trying to install the `Phalcon4` with `php7.4-fpm` and I see that the ini file for phalcon is loaded in my `phpinfo()` here

[image]

But I am still getting the below error

```
Problem 1
    - phalcon/incubator-logger[v1.0.0-beta.1, ..., v1.0.1] require ext-phalcon ^4.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's phalcon extension.
    - Root composer.json requires phalcon/incubator-logger ^1.0 -> satisfiable by phalcon/incubator-logger[v1.0.0-beta.1, v1.0.0, v1.0.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/50-phalcon.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

How can I get the Phalcon4 working for me? I am running LEMP Stack on Ubuntu 20.04

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error's indicate that you are trying to load phalcon via the CLI, your phpinfo() output is only showing that phalcon is loaded for FPM.

You need to load the extension in both config ini files:

[Documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/installation):

```
; Ubuntu/Debian with Php7-fpm: Add a File Called 30-phalcon.ini in /etc/php7/fpm/conf.d/ with This Content:
extension=phalcon.so

; Ubuntu/Debian with Php7-cli: Add a File Called 30-phalcon.ini in /etc/php7/cli/conf.d/ with This Content:
extension=phalcon.so
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to run phalcon  PSR module
Execute this command start the php-fpm server

```
sudo apt install php7.4-psr
sudo start php7.4-fpm
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).